# ActiveMQ broker listed in remote process - not able to find installation path

Tags: activemq-classic, jconsole

I have a kind of black-box application as it was developed by vendor. I could see all the topic and queues when I login to JConsole with this URL as remote process `localhost:35099`, but I am not seeing the ActiveMQ installation directory.

Is there any way to verify how broker is installed or determine which JVM it uses? What other things do I need to look out to figure out the ActiveMQ details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broker runs as a Java process, so you can find where the base directory of the running process, and then look for the data directory (sometimes the data is moved to a different location).

For the java.home location (ie ActiveMQ's operating base directory)

```
java.lang:type=Runtime
```

Look on the attribute:

```
SystemProperties
```

It's type is 'javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport. Click into it.. then scroll through the list until you find the SystemProperty

```
java.home
```

There should be a JMX bean for the broker:

```
org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=.. your broker name..
```

Then look for the attribute to see where data is stored:

```
DataDirectory /opt/activemq/../data
```